# SELECT * FROM questions WHERE test_id

Tags: mysql, sql, arrays

I have two SQL tables:

### Tests

```
id | name
1  | simple
2  | advanced
3  | professional
```

### Questions

```
id | Question                    | answer a | answer b | test_id
1  | Working?                    | Yes      | no       | 1,3
2  | Do you smoke?               | Yes      | no       | 2,3
3  | You have a driving license? | Yes      | No       | 2
```

Questions should be displayed only if in "test_id" is the id of the desired test, for example, test 2 should contain only questions 2 and 3

```
SELECT * FROM questions WHERE... (array "test_id" contains 2)
```

It isn't duplicate, because in suggested question is query like "WHERE ... value=(1,2,3,4)", but in my problem, I have query like "... WHERE (1,2,3,4,5)=value" it's opposite and method "in" is not correct.

Comment: You certainly should not store data like this ( I am talking about comma-separated values here), you should normalize your table to do what you want without unnecessary headaches like splitting strings.

Comment: You should use, "." operator. So that you can compare the values, Tests.id = Questions.id.
Then you can print the data which matches this condition.

Comment: Which database you use sql server, mysql, oracle...? And yes you should shouldn't store data like this if you can change data structure

Comment: Serlite -> thanks for editing, much better to see :)

I use mysql

I can change comma to dot, is no problem

Can you write an SQL query?
please.... :)

Comment: You should normalize, like suslov said, but until then, you can use [`FIND_IN_SET`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set). Similar questions have been asked many times before.

Comment: I spent several hours on searching the answer...
"in" not working in my problem it is opposite I suppose...

Comment: Hi, why my question get two negative votes?
It isn't duplicate, because in suggested question is query like "WHERE ... value=(1,2,3,4)", but in my problem, I have query like "... WHERE (1,2,3,4,5)=value" it's opposite and method "in" is not correct.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should [normalize](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) your database, creating a third table to link questions with the tests they appear on:

**Tests:**

```
id | name
1  | simple
2  | advanced
3  | professional
```

**Questions:**

```
id | question                    | answer a | answer b
1  | Working?                    | Yes      | No
2  | Do you smoke?               | Yes      | No
3  | You have a driving license? | Yes      | No
```

**TestQuestions:**

```
id | test_id | question_number | question_id
1  | 1       | 1               | 1
2  | 2       | 1               | 2
3  | 2       | 2               | 3
4  | 3       | 1               | 1
5  | 3       | 2               | 2
```

You can then fetch the questions for an individual test by joining the TestQuestions table with Questions:

```
    SELECT Questions.*
      FROM TestQuestions
INNER JOIN Questions ON Questions.id = TestQuestions.question_id
     WHERE TestQuestions.test_id = 2
  ORDER BY TestQuestions.question_number
```

If you are unable to modify your database tables, then you could also determine the questions in a test using MySQL's [`FIND_IN_SET`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) function:

```
SELECT * From Questions WHERE FIND_IN_SET('2', test_id) > 0
```

It is preferable to use the normalized database structure though since this allows the ordering of questions on a test to be expressed and indexes can also be created to allow better performance.

To evaluate the `FIND_IN_SET` query, the database must consider every row in the Questions table to see if it matches. By adding the following index to the normalized database, the database would be able to seek directly to the relevant questions for a test:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX test_id_question_number ON TestQuestions (test_id, question_number)
```

Comment: It's worth pointing out that this is typically called a "many-to-many" relationship.

Comment: Sound advice, but not really a good answer, because it doesn't supply one of the multiple hands-on solutions, while it does suggest to do a lot of work which my not even be possible for OP. The answer would be better if it also contains a solution for the current table structure.

Comment: @GolezTrol I have added a "hands-on" solution using `FIND_IN_SET` and explained why normalization would be preferable.

Comment: @ Phil Ross Your answer about third table is the best solution. I use this method to select the questions.

@Aleksandar Miladinovic Your method "regexp" is exactly what I was looking for, but I not thought about more that 10 tests, so if a have 11, 12,...19 tests and need questions for test 1 I get all of questions from test 1, 11, 12...to 19 because this contain "1"

Once again,  Thank You all. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You really should include another table that maps the question to the test. The way you have it now, the questions cannot be easily linked to the test. For example, if you try to use use a LIKE comparison you may get questios back you didn't intend.  Say you are looking for questions to test 2

```
SELECT * FROM questions WHERE test_id LIKE %2%;
```

You would also retrieve items for tests 12, anything in the 20s and 32, 42, etc.

You should create a new table called testquestions (for example).  This would have two fields

- test_id
- question_id

And then this data (using what you showed above)

```
test_id  |  question_id
1        |  1
2        |  2
2        |  3
3        |  1
3        |  2
```

Now you can run a query like this

```
SELECT 
  tests.name,
  questions.question,
  questions.`answer a`,
  questions.`answer b`
FROM (
  tests LEFT JOIN testquestions ON test.id=testquestion.test_id 
) LEFT JOIN
questions ON questions.id = testquestion.question_id 
WHERE 
  tests.id = 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to search one test id at a time you can use

```
SELECT * FROM questions WHERE (',' + test_id + ',') like '%,1,%'
```

Comment: What if there's a test with id 10? or 11,  12, 13, 14, etc.?

Comment: This will give a false positive if `10` is in the list. Hint, changing it to `%,1,%` also doesn't work. You could change it to `CONCAT(',', test_id, ',') like '%,1,%'`, but as you can see it's getting ugly pretty soon.

Comment: This would work okay for small data sets but if there were a lot of questions this would perform poorly due to the forced full table scan caused by `like '%1%'` not to mention the issue when the numbers go into double digits.

Comment: Yes, i know that. it can't by like %

Comment: @GolezTrol I've seen your comment after I've already edited my answer :)

Comment: @Robbert I stand corrected. Better think more next time I post an answer.

Answer (score 0):

i think the best solution offer you Phil Ross (only think i would change will be that i would store this Yes/No answer as true/false OR small int and 0/1)... But if you want to keep your table like they are you can do something like this

```
SELECT q.* FROM Questions q
INNER JOIN tests t
ON t.id = 2 
AND q.test_id regexp(CONCAT('(^|,)',t.id, '(,|$)'));
```

Here is [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/76ee1/2) to see how it's work...

P.S. The query connect and the first table so you can select value from there if it's needed...

GL!

EDIT: Fixed on Phil suggestion... Tnx Phil :)

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, but I'll do a third table for mapping.
Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Your query will return all the rows with test ids that contain the digit 2 (2, 12, 20, 21, 22, ...). To use [`REGEXP`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp) to find questions for test id 2, you'll need something like this: `SELECT * FROM Questions WHERE test_id REGEXP '(^|,)2(,|$)'`.

Comment: You're welcome... Definitely that would be the best solution to listen Phil... @PhilRoss you'll right and about this... Here is [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/76ee1/2) fixed... Tnx for that note...